# What is causing keras value error using tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, keras, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have been trying to run a neural net model using Keras on some .tfrecord files I have already generated. To do this I am passing them in as command line arguments and storing in a tensorflow dataset which I am then using to fit the model. However when I run the code I get the following error: `ValueError: Please provide either inputs and targets or inputs, targets, and sample_weights`. It seems like Keras is angry I am not passing separate input and label tensors but I have been led to believe you can use the dataset as a single argument instead? The code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import tensorflow.data
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

tf.enable_eager_execution()

inputList = []
for file in sys.argv[0:]:
    inputList.append(file)    
filenames = tf.Variable(inputList, tf.string)
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset.shuffle(1600000)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(13, input_shape=(13,), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```